How to achieve proper allignment of outer head element on even pages?
I am writing a twosided document which has 2 authors. I want both of them to be denoted on the outer headline field with the names alligned to the outer border of the head box. The relevant code for this that I am currently using is:
\documentclass[
    english,
    paper=a4,
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV=11,
    twoside=semi,
    headsepline=true,
    headheight=27.2pt% headheight for the 2 line head
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Meta data
\newcommand{\AuthorOne}{John Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorTwo}{Jimmy Doe}
\newcommand{\addinfo}{report}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{Title}

% Header settings
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor}
\ihead{
    \\
    \addinfo
}
\chead{
    \\
    \doctitle
}
\ohead{
    \AuthorOne\\
    \AuthorTwo
}

% Title
\title{\doctitle}
\author{
    \AuthorOne\and
    \AuthorTwo
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}

Everything looks fine on odd pages:

However, on even pages the names appear to be wrongly alligned (or there is some spacing added, but as far as my testing went it does not come from the newline I used in the \ohead setting):

How can I achieve the authors to be alligned to the left on even pages?

Missing % at the end of lines add spaces

\documentclass[
    english,
    paper=a4,
    fontsize=11pt,
    DIV=11,
    twoside=semi,
    headsepline=true,
    headheight=27.2pt% headheight for the 2 line head
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Meta data
\newcommand{\AuthorOne}{John Doe}
\newcommand{\AuthorTwo}{Jimmy Doe}
\newcommand{\addinfo}{report}
\newcommand{\doctitle}{Title}

% Header settings
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalcolor}
\ihead{%
    \\
    \addinfo
}
\chead{%
    \\
    \doctitle
}
\ohead{%
    \AuthorOne\\
    \AuthorTwo
}

% Title
\title{\doctitle}
\author{%
    \AuthorOne\and
    \AuthorTwo
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum

\lipsum
\end{document}

